# Would Mordechai have to check the king's clothing for shatnez?

Tags: clothing, megillat-esther, shaatnez, mordechai

In Esther 6:11 Mordechai was dressed in the royal clothing. Did Mordechai have to ascertain whether or not the clothes contained shatnez or was he allowed to wear them without checking?

Comment: I wonder if actors have to check the costumes they wear in productions.  The cases seem related.

Comment: Why would this be different from any other piece of clothing?

Comment: Did the clothes belong to Mordechai or the King of Persia?

Comment: Also refusing to wear the royal garb may have been pikuach nefesh

Comment: @ezra Why does ownership matter?

Comment: @DanF I don't know for sure but I seem to recall a halacha in which if the clothing doesn't belong to you you there's no chashash for shatnez, same as in tzitzis-obligated garments; if the garment isn't yours you don't need to attach tzitzis until 30 days have passed. I don't know if they are related but perhaps they are?

Comment: @ezra I think it's easy to prove that the clothes Mordechai wore were temporary and belonged to the king. (I'm assuming it's the story when he rode on the horse. The later one about his wearing royal garments after the decree was reversed may be a different thing.) Thus, if you can find a source backing what you stated, you can compose an answer.

Comment: @ezra no, ownership doesn't matter for shaatnez

Comment: @ezra Given what DoubleAA stated, I'm inclined to concur with sabbahillel's thinking. The phrasing in the Megilla says *Vayalbesh oto* - "They dressed him". It could imply a sense that they forced him to dress this way. Seems similar to the phrasing regarding when Yosef was first appointed "minister" and it also says that they dressed him in royal clothes.

Comment: Mordechai as a member of the Sanhedrin and therefore required to be proficient in many matters not necessary to most Rabbanim was quite likely also  perfectly capable of looking at the clothing and knowing whether they were Shaatnez.  (Back then I highly doubt that it was necessary to cut open clothing to inspect the lining. The whole garment was probably made the same way.)

Comment: Not sure if the intention of the below sources would cover shatnez, but they seem to be on the topic:

**Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 178:2**: "One who is close with the authorities and is required to dress in their clothing and to be similar to them, is permitted in all respects."

**Mishne Torah Hilchot Avoda Zara 11:3**: "An Israelite of an idolatrous king's circle, who must sit in council together with their kings, and he feels ashamed to appear different than they, may wear their kind of clothes and shave opposite his face as they do."

Comment: @sabbahillel your comment above was correct, see answer below

Answer (score 1):

As sabbahillel suggested in comments

> there was no concern regarding the prohibition of wearing shaatnez:
>   Mordechai was permittted to do so since he would be endangering
>   himself by not obeying the King's request (Sifsei Chachamim to
>   Megillah 16a, quoted in R Yosef Deutsch's [Let my nation live](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/LLIH.html), p.
>   293)